# Problem in ordering of the $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, euclidean-domain

The question given in Rudin is that ,

> prove that there doesn't exist an order such that $\mathbb{C} $turns into an ordered field.

> An order on S is a relation with the following properties
> (i) If x,y $\in S$ then any one of the following should hold true  $x<y$ ,$x=y$  or $y<x$
> (ii) If $x<y$,$y<z$ then $x<z$

Since I have read some portions of euclidean domain,  my question is what is wrong if I define a Norm in $\mathbb{C}$ as $a^2 + b^2$ and then try to order the complex numbers as $a+ib < c+id$ if and only if the norm is less .What is wrong in this ?

Comment: Did you mis-quote? Can't understand your statement.

Comment: that's just the modulo squared, so you are defining numbers bigger or smaller in terms of distence from the origin. According to that definition, -3>2.

Comment: We have $i^2=-1$. But in an ordered field, squares are $\ge 0$, so $-1\ge 0$, contradiction.

Comment: @Dietrich .So if this happens then it ain't possible to define a norm on C .I am sorry if I am making a stupid remark I am very new to this

Comment: We can define a norm on $\Bbb C$, yes, but it does not make $\Bbb C$ an ordered field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing that is wrong with this is that trichotomy fails.

We need *exactly* one of the following to happen:  i) $w < z$ or ii) $z < w$ or iii) $z = w$.

Consider if $w=a + bi$ and $z = c + di$ and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$ but $a\ne c$ and $b\ne d$.  (Any two points on a circle centered at $0$ will have this property.  Ex.  $w = i$ and $z = 1$.)

Then you have none of $w < z$ or $z < w$ or $z =w$ true.

.......

But consider the dictionary order:

$a+ bi < c + di$ if either $a < c$ or if $a=c$ and $b < d$.

That *is* a valid ordet that doesn satisfy trichotomy.

If $w =a +bi$ and $z= c+di$ then we have the follow 5 cases:

Case 1:  $a < c$.  Then $w < z$; it is not true that $z < w$; and $w\ne z$.

Case 2:  $a > c$ then $z < w$; it is not true that $w < z$ and $w\ne z$.

Case 3: $a =c$ and $b < d$.  Then $w < z$; it is not true that $z < w$; and $w\ne z$.

Case 4: $a=c$ and $b > d$. then $z < w$; it is not true that $w < z$ and $w\ne z$.

Case 5:  $a=c$ and $b = d$.  Then $w=z$ and it is not true that $w < z$ and it is not true if $z< w$.

That is a perfectly okay *order*.... but it is not an ordered *field*.

.......

There are *many* ways to order $\mathbb C$ but none of these allow $\mathbb C$ to be an ordered *field*.

You left out the *THIRD* requirement.

> An *ordered field* is a field with an order relation where the followin are true:  i) for all $a, b,c$ with $b < c$ then $a + b < a+c$ and ii) for all $a > 0$ and $b,c$ with $b< c$ then $ab < ac$.

This will lead to a requirements that if $x >0$ then $-x < 0$ (because $x + (-x) > 0 + (-x)$) and that if $x \ne 0$ then $ x^2 > 0$.  (if $x > 0$ then $x*x > 0*x$ and if $x < 0$ then $(-x) > 0$ and $(-x)(-x) > 0 (-x)$)

So $\mathbb C$ can never be an ordered field becuase $i^2 = -1$ and $1^2 = 1$ and we can't have both $1 > 0$ and $-1> 0$.

.......

Note the dictionary order fails to make an ordered field.  We have $i > 0$ (because $i =0 + i > 0 + 0i=0$ because $0 = 0$ but $1 > 0$) and yet $i^2 = -1 < 0$ (because $-1 < 0$ so $-1 + 0i < 0 + 0i=0$) .  But we if $i>0$ we need to have $i^2 = i*i > i*0=0$.  And we don't.

So the dictionary order fails to be an ordered *field*.

Answer (score 1):

In your definition there is no way to distinguish $1$, $-1$, $i$ and $-i$ because $N(\pm i)=N(\pm 1)=1$.

Comment: So why cant we consider them as equal

Comment: Because indeed $i\neq -i$ as complex numbers. And you want complex numbers, right? So we would need either $-i<i$ or $i<-i$. Both does not hold with your definition.

Comment: Even in $\mathbb{Q}$, $\frac{2}{3}$ = $\frac{4}{6}$ and so on ...

Comment: @smita Even in $\mathbb{Q}$, $1\neq-1$

Comment: @Dietrich I am still not getting it , how are you saying that it is compulsory for $i<-i$ it might be possible that it is not ..

Comment: It is compulsory that *exactly* one of the following statements are true:  a) $1 < i$;  b) $i < 1$ c) $i = 1$.  Now by *your* definition $1=1+0i < 0 + 1i =i\iff 1^2 + 0^2 < 0^2+1^2$.  That is not true so $1 \not < i$.  And $i=0+1i \le 1+0i = 1 \iff 0^2 + 1^2 < 1^2 + 0^2$.  That is not true so $i \not < 1$.  And $i = 0+1i = 1+0i= 1 \iff (0,1) = (1,0) \iff 0 = 1$ and $1=0$.  That is not true so $i \ne 1$.  So *NONE* of those three are true.  So your order is not a total order.

Comment: It is compulsory that either $i < -i$ or that $-i < i$ or that $i = -i$.  $i = -i$ is impossible because $0+1i = 0 - 1i \iff (0, 1) = (0,-1)$ and $1\ne -1$.  And we don't have $-i < i $ becuase $0^2 +(-1)^2 \not < 0^2 + 1^2$ and we don't have $i < -i$ because $0^2 + 1^2 \not < 1^2 + 0^2$.  So we have *none* of the three.

Answer (score 0):

In any ordered field, every square must be positive. Because if $a > 0$ then $a^2 > 0$ and if $a < 0$ then $a^2 > 0$ (multiplying both sides by $a$ preserves the inequality if $a > 0$ and flips it if $a < 0$). But this is a problem because $1 = 1^2 > 0$ means that $1 - 1 > 0 - 1$ means that $-1 < 0$. Since $-1 < 0$ it cannot be a square because as we've established, every square must be positive.

Comment: I think that what is underlying here is if every order over a field needs necesarily be as the order of the real numbers. Take for example $z < y \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{c} ||z||<||y|| \mbox{ if $||z|| \neq ||y||$} \\ arg(z)_{mod.2\pi} < arg(y)_{mod.2\pi} \mbox{ if $||z||=||y||$} \end{array}\right.$ 

Otherwise they are equal. I have thought about this way of ordering the complex numbers before, of course is not a nice order in any sense since for example a lot of nice properties such as exactly monotonicity of $z^2$ are lost, but I think it does not fail the definition since

Comment: $0$ would be the absolute minimum over all of $\mathbb{C}$ under this definition. I haven't honestly checked this in  a very serious manner but fulfills the general definition of an order. Any thoughts? It does have another serious issue is that the order relation over the real numbers is not inherited. If that is a condition then of course there it fails, but again, what is underlying here is whether the real numbers ordering has to be preserved or not. (It does preserve the order over the positive reals tho).

Comment: @astro There is a deep connection between ordered fields and what are known as "formally real fields." A field is *formally real* if $-1$ cannot be written as a sum of squares. So yes, there is a close relationship between how ordered fields work and how the reals work with their ordering. What you describe is an ordering but it isn't an ordered field. Remember than an ordered field must satisfy $a < b \iff a + c < b + c$ (for all $c$). So if $0 < 1$ then $c < c + 1$ for every $c$ (in particular: $c = -1$). It follows that $-1 < 0$ which in turn implies that $x > 0 \iff -x < 0$.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor Gunn, I am not a specialist in algebra so I wasn't aware of the subtletie. Clearly for me that worked as an order but an ''ordered field'' definition of course might ask for more (as you point out) and that would be a different story.